# 雰囲気メガネSDK利用時にビルドエラー<duplicate symbol>

Tags: objective-c

雰囲気メガネSDKを利用したのですが、公式のサンプルソースをビルドしようとしたところ下記エラーが発生して解決できません。

https://github.com/FUNIKImegane/FunikiSDK

別のコード内で同名の変数が定義されているらしいということは分かりましたが、
対処法が分からず、情報も少ないため困っております。

ご存知の方ご教示お願いいたします。

> duplicate symbol _kHardware2015IppanHanbai in:
>    /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)
>    /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     duplicate symbol _kHardwareMakuake in:  /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)
>    /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     duplicate symbol _kLatestHardware2FirmRevision in:
>    /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)  /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     duplicate symbol _kLatestHardware2FirmVersion in:
>    /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)
>     /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     duplicate symbol _kLatestHardware3FirmRevision in:
>     /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)
>     /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     duplicate symbol _kLatestHardware3FirmVersion in:
>     /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchManager.o)
>     /Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/sandbox/Xcode_sample/Sample/FunikiSDK/libFunikiSDK.a(MAMarchDevice.o)
>     ld: 6   duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: duplicate symbolなので多重定義では？と思ってググッて見たらそれっぽいの見つけました。
http://qiita.com/conta_/items/af7c88f2d16d97985387

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
件のサイトを試してみたところ、必要なものが足りないというエラーになりました。
上記サイトは.oファイルの重複により発生していますが、
今回の件は違う.oファイル内の同一変数名重複により発生しているため、
.oファイル削除では対処できないのかなと考えています。

Comment: 原因は不明ですが、実機に繋いでビルドしてみたところビルドが成功しました。
シミュレータ上にビルドしようとすると失敗するみたいです。

Answer (score 1):

雰囲気メガネの開発チームです。SDK試していただきありがとうございます！　シュミレーターでのビルドエラーの件ご迷惑おかけしました。最新版のSDK1.0.3にて修正されていますので、こちらでお試しください。

https://github.com/FUNIKImegane/FunikiSDK

何か質問等ありましたら、またご連絡ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
また何かありましたらよろしくお願い致します。